# When adding an element, the rest ones change their position

Tags: css, button, css-position

I've just started learning HTML, JS, CSS and I created my first "project". It's an online calculator which works well (the numbers' forming, the operations, the output go as I intended) but I'm still facing problems with button positioning.

Having a total number of 24 buttons (excepting some special ones), I tried to group them in 3 lines of 8 buttons each adding them classes and using display: inline-block; and float: left; but it simply didn't work for the second and third line (the buttons were getting random positions) so I fixed their position manually (top, left, width and height). This was the first issue.
Then, when the website finally seemed to look well, I've found out that the buttons were not correctly placed on other pc or smartphones. This was the second issue (which I didn't fixed it yet).
Now I want to create a navigation bar and other pages with games and stuff, but everytime I add an element, like  the buttons go to other positions.

Please help me, as I'm a highschool student and nobody can help me. I'll assign my CSS file and if you want to see how the website looks so far it's: utilitardecalcul.w3spaces.com

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.l1{

    background-color: white;
    border: 5px solid gray;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 250px;
    top: 150px;
}
.l2{

    background-color: white;
    border: 5px solid gray;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: -710px;
    top: 270px;
}
.l4{

    background-color: white;
    border: 5px solid gray;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 610px;
    top: 150px;
}
.l3{

    background-color: white;
    border: 5px solid gray;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: -230px;
    top: 270px;
}
.m{
    background-color: white;
    border: 5px solid gray;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: -230px;
    top: 270px;
}
#Rezultat{
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    width:960px;
    height:50px;
    top:-140px;
    left:250px;
    border:5px solid gray;
    text-align: right;
    font-size:larger;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#C{
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    width:100px;
    height:410px;
    top:198px;
    left:1215px;
    border:5px solid gray;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:50px;
    font-weight:lighter;
}
#C:hover{background-color: gray }
button:hover {background-color: gray}
body {
    background-color:aqua
}
```